CORS in .NET 8 returns 405 for the Preflight
We recently migrated one of our ASP.NET Core 6 Web API to .NET 8. We just updated the target framework and left all the startups as is, using the existing ConfigureService and Configure methods.
Here is our CORS registration in our middleware:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
             {
                 options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                     policy =>
                         {
                             policy.AllowAnyMethod()
                                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                                   .WithOrigins("https://test.com") //Here we have the list of origins
                                   .AllowCredentials()
                                   .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(GlobalCorsOptions.PreflightMaxAge));
                         });
            });

services.AddSingleton<ExceptionConverter>(converter);

services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;           // Allows empty JSON body
}).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
    options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
});

services.AddResponseCaching();
services.AddApiVersioning();

services.AddSingleton<KeepAliveConfiguration>();
services.AddSingleton<OutOfServiceEvaluator>();
services.AddSingleton(LoggingClient.TelemetryClient);
services.AddSingleton(EnvironmentDefinition.AadAuthenticationSettings);
services.AddSingleton(EnvironmentDefinition.AadAuthenticationSettings.FederationMetadataCacheSettings);
services.AddSingleton<AadDal>();
services.AddSingleton<FederationMetadataCache>();

this.ConfigureAuthentication(services);

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
         {
             options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
             options.AddPolicy("Auth", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "Auth").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
         });

Initialize(services);

services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
    // add the versioned api explorer, which also adds IApiVersionDescriptionProvider service  
    // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"  
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

    // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment. the SubstitutionFormat  
    // can also be used to control the format of the API version in route templates  
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, 
IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
    // The exception handler for errors that are not handled by our controllers. 
    app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
        {
            var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.ToString());
        }));

    app.UseHsts();

    // Needed to make sure that LoggingContext is passed inside the Request when we receive calls
    app.UseInstrumentationMiddleware();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    app.UseResponseCaching();

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                {
                    Public = false,
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxAge)
                };        

            await next();
        });

    appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Application started.");
       });

    appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Application is stopping...");
           Thread.Sleep(60000);
       });

    appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Application stopped.");
           Thread.Sleep(5000);
       });

    RepositoryBase.ApplicationLifetime = appLifetime;

    if (!EnvironmentDefinition.CurrentEnvironment.Contains("PROD"))
    {
        app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
                     {
                         swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>
                             {
                                 new OpenApiServer
                                     {
                                         Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}", Description = "pre-prod"
                                     }
                             };
                     });
             });
    }
}

We are seeing an error http 405 for the Preflight request. If works when I call this from a test application on my local, however if fails when I call from the actual Angular application.
My application is deployed in AKS and we have AzureTraffic managed mapped to a Host name in the settings.
Not sure what is missing here.

The 405 error is usually caused by an OPTIONS request that was not handled correctly. So you can add options request support, and check what happened.

With the above code, i am able to get the OPTIONS call working (preflight). However, not it fails again with HEAD request method. Not sure if this is related to CORS.

Hi KNDM, we can create a free Azure Web App and see if you continue to encounter CORS errors. This allows us to troubleshoot if AKS or AzureTraffic is causing the issue.
